# DropDownList cacadierend

Tags: visual-studio-code, vb.net-to-c#

Unfortunately I do not understand that. Have already tried a lot without success. Any help welcome!

> Compilerfehlermeldung: BC30456: 'idRegion_SelectedIndexChanged' is not a member of 'vb_aspx'.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="idRegion" runat="server"
    Enabled = "False" AutoPostBack = "True"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="idRegion_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: I have asp.NET Framework and asp.NET Core and work with vb, but both got the same error.

Comment: Can't nobody help me. What else can I do?